# Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: java, android

Getting this error working with the AdView class. What is the problem? I've tried Order & Export, closing and reopening Eclipse, and pretty much every suggestion I could find on the net. Nothing worked so I'm here.

Line 14 of the XML file is:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

Here is said XML file for the activity that contains the AdView (That's not my actual id) :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".SearchActivity" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id = "@+id/adView"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
        ads:adUnitId="pub-1234567891234567" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="248dp"
        android:layout_height="392dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Search results"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the logcat:

```
05-18 16:00:00.233: I/Process(6997): Sending signal. PID: 6997 SIG: 9
05-18 16:03:29.038: I/dalvikvm(7141): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
05-18 16:03:29.038: W/dalvikvm(7141): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 511: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
05-18 16:03:29.038: D/dalvikvm(7141): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x008b
05-18 16:03:29.038: I/dalvikvm(7141): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
05-18 16:03:29.038: W/dalvikvm(7141): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 504: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
05-18 16:03:29.038: D/dalvikvm(7141): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0099
05-18 16:03:29.042: D/dalvikvm(7141): VFY: dead code 0x008e-0092 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
05-18 16:03:29.042: D/dalvikvm(7141): VFY: dead code 0x009c-00a0 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
05-18 16:03:29.116: D/skia(7141): purging 6K from font cache [1 entries]
05-18 16:03:29.116: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): stored typeface in slot 0
05-18 16:03:29.116: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): SKIA_FONT fontfile: /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/default/DroidSans.ttf
05-18 16:03:29.116: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): SKIA_FONT fontfile: /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/default/DroidSans.ttf
05-18 16:03:29.116: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans, style = 0, uniqueID = 13
05-18 16:03:29.120: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): SKIA_FONT fontfile: /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/default/DroidSans-Bold.ttf
05-18 16:03:29.120: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): SKIA_FONT fontfile: /data/data/com.android.settings/app_fonts/default/DroidSans-Bold.ttf
05-18 16:03:29.120: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans, style = 1, uniqueID = 14
05-18 16:03:29.128: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Serif, style = 0, uniqueID = 15
05-18 16:03:29.135: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Serif, style = 1, uniqueID = 16
05-18 16:03:29.143: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Serif, style = 2, uniqueID = 17
05-18 16:03:29.167: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Serif, style = 3, uniqueID = 18
05-18 16:03:29.171: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Mono, style = 0, uniqueID = 19
05-18 16:03:29.171: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Arabic, style = 0, uniqueID = 20
05-18 16:03:29.171: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Hebrew, style = 0, uniqueID = 21
05-18 16:03:29.175: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Thai, style = 0, uniqueID = 22
05-18 16:03:29.178: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans, style = 0, uniqueID = 23
05-18 16:03:29.198: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), name = Droid Sans Fallback, style = 0, uniqueID = 24
05-18 16:03:29.198: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), oldSansUID = 1, newSansUID = 13
05-18 16:03:29.198: D/SKIA_FONT(7141): load_system_fonts(), oldSansBoldUID = 2, newSansBoldUID = 14
05-18 16:03:32.210: D/SearchDialog(7141): launching Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEARCH flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.activity2/.SearchActivity (has extras) }
05-18 16:03:32.214: I/SearchDialog(7141): Starting (as ourselves) #Intent;action=android.intent.action.SEARCH;launchFlags=0x10000000;component=com.example.activity2/.SearchActivity;S.query=J;S.user_query=J;end
05-18 16:03:32.288: I/System.out(7141): file is /mnt/sdcard
05-18 16:03:32.292: W/dalvikvm(7141): VFY: unable to resolve static field 4641 (AdsAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
05-18 16:03:32.292: D/dalvikvm(7141): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0009
05-18 16:03:32.292: D/dalvikvm(7141): VFY: dead code 0x000b-0068 in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/ao;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
05-18 16:03:32.303: D/AndroidRuntime(7141): Shutting down VM
05-18 16:03:32.303: W/dalvikvm(7141): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
05-18 16:03:32.339: D/dalvikvm(7141): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3272 objects / 222072 bytes in 30ms
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.activity2/com.example.activity2.SearchActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:200)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.example.activity2.SearchActivity.onCreate(SearchActivity.java:76)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     ... 11 more
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     ... 21 more
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.ao.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.au.<init>(Unknown Source)
05-18 16:03:32.358: E/AndroidRuntime(7141):     ... 25 more
05-18 16:08:37.901: I/Process(7141): Sending signal. PID: 7141 SIG: 9
```

Any suggestions? Been trying to get this very simple AdView to work all day. Thanks.

Comment: Google play services is not attached properly remove and add again then try.

Comment: Have you configured your project to include google play services?  If using Android Studio, check your build.gradle file for your app and make sure you have a compile dependency for com.google.android.gms:play-services:x.x.x

Comment: @MichaelKrause Yes, I have. I'm using eclipse, but I see a build.gradle file and I don't see google.android.gms:play-services included in there. Why does my code compile in the first place if that's not there, and how do I resolve the issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
     ads:adUnitId="pub-1234567891234567" //<< who is that the id? by design?`

Comment: @Elltz I just put a dummy id in there. Disregard.

Comment: @yoyoyo: If you are using Eclipse, the build.gradle file is superfluous.  In your case, follow the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html (choose the instructions for "Using Eclipse with ADT")

Comment: @MichaelKrause Thanks, but when I go to add projects, I select "Add" to bring up the projects and the menu is blank. I have the google-play-services JAR in the sdk folder so I'm not sure what's going on. This is where google-play-services is:   ...\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\google-play-services.jar

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/com.google.ads"
```

with

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

The namespace is under the lib name not libs.

and make sure you have the google play services in your  build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: what is the downvote for? I tried this code and it's working fine.

Comment: well for starters i think you need to re-read the question you might get the reason for your downvote

Comment: I read the questiion. The error is line 14 of the XML and if you check the XML he is using /libs but the correct one is /lib. I tried it in my machine and that is the fixed and I can see the adView now.  So why downvote?

Comment: and I am not even a starter , I have been a member of SO for 4 years and 7 months. :)

Comment: That's a good catch but didn't fix my issue. Was it giving you the same problem that I have now before that fix? If so, thanks, because I may have never caught that.

Comment: so what is the error now? Can you post your gradle file as well?

Comment: well you a veteran no doubt, i'm a newbie here myself but i do not think op is using build.gradle so maybe state a condition on your answer because it will then invalid, those are my thoughts but im not the downvoter,

Comment: he is using Eclipse but there is a gradle plugin for Eclipse so we can never be sure of what he is using. Could be maven. Anyway, if you can post the maven details that can be helpful. thanks.

Comment: @Christian-PMP Same exact error. And disregard anything I've said about a gradle file. Just realized that I was looking at a sample in a completely different folder...No gradle file in my project folder. Maybe you can address my comment in Michael's answer? For some reason, I am not able to add a reference to the google-play-services.jar library project.

Answer (score -3):

Don't put `google-play-services.jar` in the `/libs/` folder. Instead, reference the google play services library in your project.

Import the library into your workspace. You'll find it in `sdk/extras/google/..` if you downloaded via the sdk manager. Then reference by right clicking your project => selecting properties => Android => Add

First attached Google play services in your app properly, then add xml-name-space in layout xml file.

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

then use this

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="Your AddUnitID" />
```

add this in `manifiest.xml`

```
    <activity
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Did you read my question? I've done everything you've suggested here.

Comment: what reason for negative don't discourage developers... thanks